# Optimising Android file writing

Tags: android, file-io

I am currently writing an android app that logs the accelerometer. (its a test app at the moment so i can prototype an algorithm.

To write out a list of `SensorEventStore`'s (which is just a way of storing the data from a `SensorEvent`) to the SD card from a 30 minute recording, locks up the GUI for about 20 - 30 seconds while writing the file.

I am using the following code to write out the file to the SD card.

```
@Override
public void onMessage(Messages message, Object param[]) {
    if(message == IDigest.Messages.SaveData) {
        File folder = (File) param[0];

        File accFileAll = new File(folder, startTime + "_all.acc");

        FileWriter accFileWriterAll;

        try {
            accFileWriterAll = new FileWriter(accFileAll);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            accFileWriterAll = null;
        }

        for(Iterator<SensorEventStore> i=eventList.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
            SensorEventStore e = i.next();

            if(accFileWriterAll != null) {
                try {
                    accFileWriterAll.write(
                        String.format(
                            "%d,%d,%f,%f,%f\r\n",
                            e.timestamp,
                            e.accuracy,
                            e.values[0],
                            e.values[1],
                            e.values[2]
                        )
                    );

                    accFileWriterAll.flush();
                } catch (IOException ex) {

                }
            }
        }

        new SingleMediaScanner(RunBuddyApplication.Context, accFileAll);
    }
}
```

Can anyone give me any pointers to make this not lock up the UI, or not have to take the amount of time it currently takes to write out the file.

Comment: Buffering, binary instead of text if possible and background threads/asynctasks should help.

Comment: Write it on a separate thread.  You shouldn't do I/O on the GUI thread?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should try to do this in the background. The [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) is fairly well suited for the task.

Other than that, you should remove the `flush()` statement, and probperly `close()` your file writer. The `flush` causes the data to be written to disk in rather small portions, which is really slow. If you leave the filewriter to its own flushing, it will determine a buffer size on its own. When you properly close the `FileWriter`, the remaining data should be written to disk as well.

Also, you could take a look at "Try with resources" for your filewriter, but that is optional.